# Django and Jinja2 randomize form fields display

Tags: python, django, forms, jinja2

I have the following situation:

**forms.py**

```
REASONS = [
    {'code': 1, 'reason': 'I want to unsubscribe'},
    {'code': 2, 'reason': 'I hate this site'}]

Myform(forms.Form):
    magic_field = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def __init__(self):
        # Depending on the REASONS list add the fields to the form
        for key in REASONS:
            self.fields['reason_{}'.format(key['code'])] = forms.BooleanField(
                label=_(key['reason']),
                widget=widgets.CheckboxInput())
```

What I want is to have the order the reasons rendered in randomized order.

**template.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url unsubscribe %}">
    {% if some_event %}
        {{ form.magic_field }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form.reason_1 }} # <-- randomize this order
    {{ form.reason_2 }} # <-- randomize this order
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried importing `random` on your forms.py and then shuffling `REASONS` ? Im not sure if that would shuffle it once and call it a night, or shuffle it each time it comes up though.

Comment: @TehTris yes, the problem is as I explained below in pleasedontbelong answer

Comment: okay i see. using django itself, you may be able to create a custom filter that you can apply to it ( in the template it would end up looking like `{{ form | filter_name }}` ) Other than that, the only other way i can think if would be if you used PHP or Javascript to shuffle the `{{form.reason_1}}` and `{{form.reason_2}}` in the template directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you shuffle the REASONS first and then use a `{% for %}` loop in the template?

Something like:

```
REASONS = [
    {'code': 1, 'reason': 'I want to unsubscribe'},
    {'code': 2, 'reason': 'I hate this site'}]

Myform(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        random.shuffle(REASONS) # use some magic method to shuffle here
        for key in REASONS:
             ...

<form method="POST" action="{% url unsubscribe %}">

    {% for field in form %} #cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Hope this helps

**Edit**
You could create a filter or a function (i'd use a function) something like

```
{% if some_event %}
    {{ form.magic_field }}
{% endif %}
{% for field in form %}
    {% if is_reason_field(field) %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

on your helpers.py something like: (I don't know how exactly do this)

```
@register.function
def is_reason_field(field):
    # i'm not sure if field.name exists, you should inspect the field attributes
    return field.name.startswith("reason_"):
```

hmm now that I see it, you could do this directly in the template since you are using jinja2

Comment: I'm aware of random.shuffle() the problem is my template can't iterate over all the fields, I have to specifically call the field name, see updated question.